# How can I add 2 cells in a CSV file in WPF?

Tags: c#, csv

I use the `OpenFileDialog` in my WPF program to give the user the option to select a .csv file and read it into the program. Now I have the path and everything from the file that the user wants and now I want to add 2 more cells to the Excel file after a button click. How should I change it so that as soon as the button is pressed, 2 columns and cells are added to the previously imported Excel file. Here is my `OpenFileDialog` how I get the file OpenFileDialog::

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
            openFileDialog.Filter = "CVS (*.cvs)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            openFileDialog.Title = "CVS Datei Auswählen zum Konvertieren";
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                foreach (string filename in openFileDialog.FileNames)
                {
                    tbxFiles.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename));

                    string temp;
                    var fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        temp = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        test = temp;
                    }

                }
                   
                
            }
```

SaveFileDialog:

```
 SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "CVS (*.cvs)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            List<String> liste = new List<String>();

           // test = test + "Hallo;";

            //File.WriteAllText(dialog.FileName, test);

            int counter = 0;
            string line;

            // Read the file and display it line by line.  
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(test);
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (counter == 0)
                {
                    line += ",column1,column2";
                }
                else
                {
                    line += $",{""},{""}";
                }

                counter++;
            }

            file.Close();

        }
```

In my "test" string I have now read in what is in the cvs file via streamreader. This is what the cvs Header looks like:

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOW2s.png)

and so how i want it look like after my C# change:

[Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8wFS.png)

`tbxFiles` = my TextBox where the path of the selected file is shown.

So how can I add additional Excel columns with associated cells to the imported Excel file in Code Behind 2?

Comment: Do you mean you just want to append two comma separated values to each line in the file?

Comment: The csv file can be called up in Excel and I want this Excel file that I read in to get two extra columns with a text in it when I click a button

Comment: open the csv file with a text editor and you'll see that you can just append **C**omma **S**eperated **V**alues to get more columns when you open the .csv in excel later.  So you just need to read the file line by line, modify the line and save it in a list then overwrite the file with the modified lines https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-a-text-file-one-line-at-a-time

Comment: Ok but every time I write a text it always places it at the end of the table, but if I change the header of columns 3 and 4 in the first line, how do you have to write it?

Comment: You didn't post any Excel-related code. CSV files are just text files. Excel files are ZIP packages containing XML files. You can't just append strings to an Excel file

Comment: Your code reads text lines from a text file, it doesn't import columns and cells. The text lines are still text lines. You could use eg `File.ReadAllLines` or `File.ReadLines` to read them. Since you have strings, not cells, adding another line is easy - just add that line first wherever you want the file lines to go. If you want to insert the lines into a list, insert the "column" line first.

Comment: Are you able to post a screenshot of how the data looks when it is read into the program?  I think this would add more context to the question.

Comment: so i changed the question, i Hope that may help

Comment: Thanks.  For further clarification, you mention about changing columns 3 & 4, but could that be any column?  For instance, you can change 1 & 5.

What is amending the columns and the data for the converted file?  Is this done through the User Interface?

Comment: Yes, it could be every column that I specify in the code but which column it is. The user should only read in a Csv file and convert it automatically with the new columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
....
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (counter == 0)
    {
        line += ",column1,column2";
    }
    else
    {
        line += $",{value1},{value2}";
    }

    counter++;
}
...
```